# App crashing when using push_back method for a vector of smart pointers

Tags: c++

I have a test application for a assignment where I have to push_back a shared pointer into a vector of shared pointers.  However it is crashing on the push_back and I am not sure why.

I tried moving the shared_ptr instead of copying it to the vector and am still seeing the same issue.  I tried to debug the issue, but for some reason the variables are not showing up in the debugger after I click on them (possible IDE issue).  I did see a similar issue on stack overflow, but this is not the same issue as the shared pointer is being initialized before the push_back is called.

```
//Fill - will loop through and ask the user what elements to add
void fill(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Test>> &vec, int num)
{
    for(int i {1}; i <= num; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter data pointer [" << i << "] : ";
        int data {};
        std::cin >> data;
        std::shared_ptr<Test> data_ptr = std::make_shared<Test> (data);
        std::cout << "Created shared pointer for " << data_ptr->get_data() << 
        std::endl; //debug
        vec.push_back(std::move(data_ptr));
        std::cout << "Added to vector" << data_ptr->get_data() << std::endl; 
        //debug (crash issue is with the pushback method)
    }
}
```

The program is crashing when after the shared_ptr is created and the push_back method doesn't appear to execute.  I added cout debug messages to try and see where in this function the program is failing.  the "created shared ptr" is called, but the "Added to vector" is not called.

Comment: What is `Test`? Also, what is `get_data()`? I don't see it as part of the [`std::shared_ptr` API](https://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)...

Comment: Do you see this in your console? `std::cout << "Created shared pointer for " << data_ptr->get_data() << std::endl;`

Comment: get_data() is returning the int that is stored as part of the Test class.   I am seeing the "Created shared pointer for" cout text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move from a `shared_ptr` the moved from variable is invalid (in this case null).

You call `data_ptr->get_data()` before pushing, which is fine. But after you push (via move) calling `data_ptr->get_data()` a second time will use the (now moved-from) smart pointer - hence your crash.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have fixed move.  After sleeping on it I noticed that how I was creating the vector in the first place was incorrect and it was crashing when putting objects into that vector.  I have fixed this and my program is now working.